# Pop Up Message before saving a record

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a requirement to have a custom pop up, that needs to pop up before saving a record in an interactive grid.

Is there any way to implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using APEX 5.1 and here's how you can achieve this. You might have to hide the default SAVE button and create a new one for this example. First, navigate to your IG region > Advanced > Static ID and enter gridID.Then, under Rendering, navigate to your Page Properties > CSS > Inline and add the following:

```
#gridID button[data-action="save"] {
display: none !important;
}
```

Now, you want to create a new region on this page and this the modal dialog.Layout > Position: Inline Dialogs. Appearance>Template: Inline Dialog. Advanced > Static ID: dialog (or something unique).
Create two buttons in this region: Cancel and Ok. 
Create a button in the IG region: SAVE.
Create the following three Dynamic Actions:
Create a DA on the Save button. For True > Action, select Execute JavaScript Code and enter the following:

```
openModal('dialog'); // use here the Static ID of modal dialog
```

Create a DA on the Cancel button. Here, True > Action, select Execute JavaScript Code and enter the following:

```
closeModal('dialog');
```

Create a DA on the OK button. For True > Action: select Submit Page and for Settings > Request / Button Name, enter OK.
Now, navigate to Processing and select the process to save the interactive grid data. In the properties, for Server-side Condition > When Button Pressed, select OK.

Navigate to the SAVE button. In the properties, Advanced > Static ID, enter savenew.
Navigate to Page properties, under JavaScript > Execute when Page Loads, enter the following code:

```
var oldbn = document.querySelector('#gridID button[data-action="save"]');
    var newbn = document.querySelector('#savenew');
    oldbn.parentNode.insertBefore(newbn, oldbn);
```